# Concatenate dynamically pivoted columns for a variable number of columns

Tags: sql-server, pivot, string-concatenation

I have been able to successfully pivot different field values into separate columns but what I want is to concatenate all of those separate (pivoted) columns into one column. I don't know how many pivoted columns that I end up with at runtime so I can't just use Column1 + Column2 + Column3 etc.

Here is my sql

```
--Create a table variable to hold my source data

declare @datatable  table
(
    OrderId             int,
    ProductId           int,
    ClientName          varchar(50)
)

--insert some data
insert into         @datatable values (1, 2, 'Joe Bloggs')
insert into         @datatable values (1, 2, 'Frank Bloggs')

--Create a temp table

--that introduces a new field (called Header)
--to give me column names for my pivoted data

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#PivotedClients') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #PivotedClients

create table        #PivotedClients
            (
               OrderId  int,
               ProductId    int,
               ClientName   varchar(50),
               Header   varchar(100)
            )

insert into     #PivotedClients
  select            OrderId,
            ProductId,
            ClientName,
            'Client ' + Cast(Rank() Over (Partition by OrderId                   
  order by ClientName) as varchar(3)) 
  from          @datatable

--Create variables to hold my column names
--and my (dynamic) sql

declare @pivotcolumns       nvarchar(max),
    @colsWithNoNulls    nvarchar(max),
    @sqlquery       nvarchar(max)

set @pivotcolumns = STUFF(
                (
                  select distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Header)
                  from #PivotedClients
                  for XML PATH (''), TYPE
                        ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
                ,1,1,'')

set @colsWithNoNulls = STUFF(
                  (
                               SELECT DISTINCT ',ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(Header) + ', '''') ' + QUOTENAME(Header)
                                        FROM #PivotedClients
         for XML PATH (''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(max)')
    ,1,1,''
        )

if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##Clients ') is not null drop TABLE ##Clients

set @sqlquery = 'select distinct OrderId,
                         ProductID,
                    ' + @colsWithNoNulls + ' 
            into        ##Clients
            from
                (
                   select   OrderId,
                                        ClientName,
                            ProductID,
                        Header
                       from #PivotedClients) x
                pivot 
                (
                   Max(ClientName)
                   for Header in (' + @pivotcolumns + ')
                )   p' 

exec sp_executesql @sqlquery

----
select *
from ##Clients
----
```

The record set that I currently end up with is:

```
OrderId ProductId  Client1       Client 2
1       2          Frank Bloggs  Joe Blogs
```

What I want is:

```
OrderID ProductId Clients
1       2         Frank Bloggs Joe Bloggs
```

I don't know how many 'pivoted' columns that I will end up with at runtime so I can't just use Client1 + Client2 etc

Comment: What version of SQL server are you using? You probably don't need to pivot at all if you just use `string_agg()` (or a stuff for xml path in versions where string_agg isn't implemented). For example, get rid of all the pivotedclients stuff and just do a simple `select orderid, productid, clients = string_agg(clientname, ' ') from @datatable group by orderid, productid;`

Comment: Thanks Dale. That's absolutely brilliant. Worked first time. Thanks you so much for your help.

Comment: @mmmg I think you meant to thank ZLK - I didn't offer any solution.

Comment: Thanks to ZLK and Thanks Dale for letting me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to change your `@colsWithNoNulls` to perform the string concatenation

```
set @colsWithNoNulls = STUFF(
                (
                    SELECT  DISTINCT '+ '' '' +  ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(Header) + ', '''')' 
                                        FROM    #PivotedClients
                    for XML PATH (''), TYPE
                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(max)')
                , 1, 1, '') + 'AS Clients'
```

Also you can do a `print @sqlquery` before `sp_executesql`. this will helps you debug your dynamic query

Comment: Hi Squirrel, thanks. Your solution worked as well. I'm going to run with Dale's solution using STRING_AGG as it eliminates the need for the complicated pivoting. I'll keep your suggestion on file just in case I'm ever using a version of SQL Server that doesn't have string_agg. Great suggestion about the print sql as it lets you see the exact sql being sent to the sql server engine.

Comment: `STRING_AGG` is only available from `SQL Server 2017` onwards